# ReportExecution2010 asmx Features

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

As currently we are using ReportExecution2005 asmx to generate the PDF/Excel format reports from C# code base. Now planning to update the service reference as ReportExecution2010.asmx.

Can some one help me to list of additional features are included in ReportExecution2010.asmx?

Answer (score 0):

Been doing a ReportServer upgrade also.

ReportExecution2005.asmx is still the service reference, and seems to work the same.  There's a ReportService2010.asmx, but it's for managing the report server not execution.